# Elastic Cache Redis maintenance window

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, elastic-cache

Is there a way a see when the maintenance for redis started, to keep track of how is going, and when is done?
I know that we can set up AWS to send notifications when is the next maintenance event( within the set up maintenance window)
but do they tell you how long is that going to be?

aws elasticache describe-events --source-type cache-cluster --region  --source-identifier  --filter-name event-source --filter-values "cache-cluster" --query "Events[?contains(Message, 'maintenance')]"

will this command show all the messages regarding the maintenance, like in progress or something?

any information regarding this will be highly appreciated

i was thinking to set up the AWS notification regarding the maintenance event
also to run this command,
aws elasticache describe-events --source-type cache-cluster --region  --source-identifier  --filter-name event-source --filter-values "cache-cluster" --query "Events[?contains(Message, 'maintenance')]"

Comment: Welcome - what's the output for `aws elasticache describe-events --source-type cache-cluster --region --source-identifier --filter-name event-source --filter-values "cache-cluster" --query "Events[?contains(Message, 'maintenance')]"`? Have you checked?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).